# Mobile app + REST API authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth-2.0

I want to build a REST API which will be used by both mobile app and also a website. I was wondering how would I go about implementing a simple login system for users?

For a simple website, after checking the username and password, one could set a `SESSION` variable and have the user "logged in".

Now, REST is stateless so I suspect that the above is not the way to go about. I thought that a possible solution would be to have the server generate and return an access token each time the user logs in, and the client will need to attach this access token to every subsequent request to access protected endpoints.

Is the above a viable solution or what is the industry standard for something like this?

(I found OAuth 2.0 to be overkill, but I could be wrong)

Answer (score 1):

There are several token authentication schemes, but if you're looking for the industry standard, then JWT (JSON Web Token) is the way to go. Here's how the process usually goes:

1. Client sends his credentials (e.g. username and password) to the server.
2. The server verifies that the credentials are correct, generates a JWT and returns it to the client. Client saves the token in e.g. localStorage.
3. For each subsequent request, the client will attach the JWT as a part of the request (usually in the "Authorization" header).
4. Server will be able to decode the JWT and decide if the client should have access to the requested resource.

Now, some interesting features of JWT come from the fact that there is data encoded in it. Some of it everyone can decode, and some only the server can decode.

So, for example, you could encode the user's id and profile picture in the JWT so that the client can use the data from it, not having to do another request to the server to get his profile.

JWT has embedded info about expiration. The server can set the expiration time.

Another cool thing about JWTs is that they are invalid if changed. Imagine you stole someone's token, but it's expired. You try to change the expire information inside the token to some time in the future, and send it to the server. Server will deem that token invalid, because the contents doesn't match the signature attached, and a valid signature can only be generated by the server.

Comment: This looks exactly like something I would need! Thanks so much. 
Does JWT stack up against OAuth 2.0? Just wondering as I heard a lot about OAuth 2.0 but not JWT